# Selecting sections in wordpress theme with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a project I am working on where I need to rearrange sections of a Wordpress theme on the front page. The sections are dynamically generated in a page composer when editing the page. I need it to just affect the front page. I have already installed a plugin that allows per post code to be applied, however I cannot figure out how to select these sections individually as they are all identical in markup. I know I could use jQuery to select based on content, however, the actual content is nested so deep I wouldn't know if the code I am using at this moment is correct, and if I need to change it or even approach it differently.

The finished mockup and the original layout can be found here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ro9KE.jpg

The code I am working with to arrange (Minus the filler content) is here:
http://pastebin.com/JCtsSxJj

It was too long to paste in a code block.

I am using the following jquery I wrote using the jQuery Docs. It doesnt seem to be working for me.

```
(function($) {
    $(".home-section .section-header .title span:contains('Category A')").css('background-color', 'blue', 'important');
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I was using the code for background color as a way to determine whether or not the code was working. I tried it both ways but it didn't work either way.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but based on [**This jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vNC88/) using your HTML, this looks like it works fine to me? Maybe your issue is not using the `$(document).ready()` wrapper?

Comment: That may be, and maybe I am just competing with waaay too many other styles, I have to figure out how to select the parent element that holds the whole segment. The code example above was a test if my selector. The Fiddle does work because the other page styles are not there already.

Comment: Maybe I am not isolating the element enough. What I am tying to do is modify the size and position of everything within the '<section class="home-section category-posts">...</section>' code.

Comment: I am trying the following in the head of the Page:
`(function($) 
 {
  $(document).ready($(".wrapper section:nth-child(2)").hasClass("category-posts").addClass("newClass"));
    })(jQuery);
`
and using `.newClass { color:red !important;}` to try and get the function to work right. It's not working at all :-/